# Outgoing mail through isp's smtp server is not getting delivered

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, smtp, mx-record, spf

What's the problem with the following emails?

1-

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: mailrelay002.isp.belgacom.be

secretariat@lagereschoolbissegem.be
[195.47.247.194]
Remote Server returned '<[195.47.247.194] #5.0.0 smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error     554-'5.7.1 <secretariat@lagereschoolbissegem.be>: Recipient address rejected: Please see     http://www.openspf.org/why.html?sender=ino%40duboccage.be&ip=195.238.6.175&receiver=mx-r.one.com' (delivery attempts: 0)>'

Original message headers:

Message-ID: <e4715c$odotdf@relay.skynet.be>
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Filtered: true
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: AksFAO6clFHCTg4N/2dsb2JhbABbglOwGQGRdxR/dIJgHDs7AUY3iBCcTI10oU8SD4JTgQYDqHKDEjo
Received: from 13.14-78-194.adsl-static.isp.belgacom.be (HELO V-FILE02)
 ([194.78.14.13])  by relay.skynet.be with ESMTP; 16 May 2013 10:49:41 +0200
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: <ino@duboccage.be>
To: <secretariat@lagereschoolbissegem.be>
```

2 -

```
Diagnostic information for administrators:

Generating server: mailrelay011.isp.belgacom.be

secretariat@debron-lovendegem.be
[195.47.247.197]
Remote Server returned '<[195.47.247.197] #5.0.0 smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 554-'5.7.1 <secretariat@debron-lovendegem.be>: Recipient address rejected: Please see     http://www.openspf.org/why.html?sender=ino%40duboccage.be&ip=195.238.6.178&receiver=mx-q.one.com' (delivery attempts: 0)>'
```

But the email adresses exists.

I thought i already fixed the spf records, so it (shouldn't) be that. Still, the mail seems to be filtered as spam...

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail is being sent from `195.238.6.178`, but at time of writing your domain's SPF record says

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ip4:195.13.7.0/27 -all
```

The sending IP address isn't included in the SPF record, and it is configured to fail hard (`-all`).

You should ask your ISP for a list of addresses (or a CIDR block) for their outbound mail servers and add that to your SPF record.  For now, you could change to `~all` at the end (soft fail).

Comment: soft fail versus hard fail is very usefull advice, i created a temp cidr block to add the mail servers of the isp (12 of them). Just hope their static :)

Comment: They might have an SPF record you can `include` (like you've done with the `outlook.com` one).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the domain (duboccage.be) has an SPF record set up that does not allow mail to be delivered from `mailrelay011.isp.belgacom.be`, only from `mailrelay011.belgacom.be`. Short term solution would be to add `mailrelay011.isp.belgacom.be` to the SPF record:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ip4:195.13.7.0/27 a:mailrelay011.belgacom.be a:mailrelay011.isp.belgacom.be -all
```

However, you may want to consider the fact that the ISP is under no obligation to keep this name for the mailserver, it may change at any time. In order to make sure your mails get delivered, use a mail server that is in connection with your domain name and warrants for the SPF record's validity.